# add Rank Column to pandas Dataframe based on column condition

Tags: pandas, rank

What I have is below.

| DOG | Date | Steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tiger | 2021-11-01 | 164 |
| Oakley | 2021-11-01 | 76 |
| Piper | 2021-11-01 | 65 |
| Millie | 2021-11-01 | 188 |
| Oscar | 2021-11-02 | 152 |
| Foster | 2021-11-02 | 191 |
| Zeus | 2021-11-02 | 101 |
| Benji | 2021-11-02 | 94 |
| Lucy | 2021-11-02 | 186 |
| Rufus | 2021-11-02 | 65 |
| Hank | 2021-11-03 | 98 |
| Olive | 2021-11-03 | 122 |
| Ellie | 2021-11-03 | 153 |
| Thor | 2021-11-03 | 152 |
| Nala | 2021-11-03 | 181 |
| Mia | 2021-11-03 | 48 |
| Bella | 2021-11-03 | 23 |
| Izzy | 2021-11-03 | 135 |
| Pepper | 2021-11-03 | 22 |
| Diesel | 2021-11-04 | 111 |
| Dixie | 2021-11-04 | 34 |
| Emma | 2021-11-04 | 56 |
| Abbie | 2021-11-04 | 32 |
| Guinness | 2021-11-04 | 166 |
| Kobe | 2021-11-04 | 71 |

What I want is below. Rank by value of ['Steps'] column for each Date

| DOG | Date | Steps | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tiger | 2021-11-01 | 164 | 2 |
| Oakley | 2021-11-01 | 76 | 3 |
| Piper | 2021-11-01 | 65 | 4 |
| Millie | 2021-11-01 | 188 | 1 |
| Oscar | 2021-11-02 | 152 | 3 |
| Foster | 2021-11-02 | 191 | 1 |
| Zeus | 2021-11-02 | 101 | 4 |
| Benji | 2021-11-02 | 94 | 5 |
| Lucy | 2021-11-02 | 186 | 2 |
| Rufus | 2021-11-02 | 65 | 6 |
| Hank | 2021-11-03 | 98 | 6 |
| Olive | 2021-11-03 | 122 | 5 |
| Ellie | 2021-11-03 | 153 | 2 |
| Thor | 2021-11-03 | 152 | 3 |
| Nala | 2021-11-03 | 181 | 1 |
| Mia | 2021-11-03 | 48 | 7 |
| Bella | 2021-11-03 | 23 | 8 |
| Izzy | 2021-11-03 | 135 | 4 |
| Pepper | 2021-11-03 | 22 | 9 |
| Diesel | 2021-11-04 | 111 | 2 |
| Dixie | 2021-11-04 | 34 | 5 |
| Emma | 2021-11-04 | 56 | 4 |
| Abbie | 2021-11-04 | 32 | 6 |
| Guinness | 2021-11-04 | 166 | 1 |
| Kobe | 2021-11-04 | 71 | 3 |

I tried below, but it failed.

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Date')['Steps'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Your solution for me working, can you specify your problem?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you tried? It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

First your solution for me working.

Maybe need `method='dense'` and casting to integers.

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Date')['Steps'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)
```